# Reset default key binding zsh

Tags: zsh

I've modified a key binding and know I don't know how to return to what it did before.

Basically I've been trying what some key bindings did and which one worked for me and know I want to go back to the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bindkey -d
```

*Deletes all existing keymaps and reset to the default state.* (as quoted from `info zsh bindkey`.

You an also always restart `zsh`:

```
exec zsh
```

To know what is bound by default to a given key or sequence, you can do:

```
(bindkey -d; bindkey '^A')
```

(replace `^A` with the representation of the character or character sequence that is sent upon pressing the key. `^A` itself is the representation of the SOH control character (0x1 byte value) that is generally sent by terminals when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks. For example, I just ran `bindkey -M emacs "^T" transpose-chars` to restore my Ctrl+t that had been bound to something else by fzf.zsh.